# Seamless authentication between my site and StackOverflow

Tags: discussion

I'm planning on using WS-Trust and SAML to authenticate users to my site and haven't really explored other options.

What should I learn (or do) to enable a mostly seamless end user transition from my site to yours?  Do they just proxy into your site using my key, or does each one need their own account?

Comment: Please tell my OpenID will be supported.

Answer (score 2):

there is no concept of authentication with API 1.0. And if there were it would be applied to usage of the api.

there is no, should be no, and unless there is a cold snap in hades, will never be a concept of SSO with third party sites.

the user will simply have to authenticate on the stack exchange site when they navigate there.

typically this needs be done only once, as your user experience with the so sites should show.

I am not sure your use case is clear.

cheers.

Comment: Thank you... maybe I just don't understand what I'm able to do w/the api

Comment: @maker - you have access to the data to use as you see fit, with proper attribution if displayed publicly.